How does Monolith Legate work in Altered
How does Monolith Legate work in Altered?
The effect says to Sabotage after Rest, but during the Rest phase the card will have either gone to the Reserve or been discarded entirely. So will the ability still happen?


Monolith Legate will Sabotage if your Expedition failed.
There's no rules that state that an effect, once procced, needs to have the source in play to actually unfold. So with these pretty powerful mechanics, it's necessary to indeed have completed the Rest phase, as you've pointed out. And then, you (might) get a chance to Sabotage. This depends on whether or not the expedition during Dusk failed, not whether Legate is still in play / in reserve.
If you were meant to place the Legate in Reserve for this ability to work, the rules text for this ability would've been presented in a different-colored box on the card, as with Foundry Mechanic for instance.

I think I was more worried about having Not to place the Legate in reserve. Keeping it in an expedition with Asleep or Anchored to make the ability function.

@Jontia Can't find anything in the rules that says Legate needs to remain in play after Phase 4, where you check its condition...

Phase 4 being Dusk? Yeah me either. It just seems a bit off track for most (read MTG) TCGs I've played.

@Jontia Yeah, Phase 4 is Dusk, as seen on their quick-reference Rules PDF, top-left 2nd page.
